# layout_gravity error in FrameLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Eclipse gives me:
**error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_gravity' with value 'center_vertical | right').**

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical | right"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

When I switch to Graphical layout it's all as I expected.
`android:minSdkVersion="10"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the spaces on either side of the "|" character

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
```

Comment: I am having the same problem as vovahost, yet don't have any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove white spaces:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```